# for loop in aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, for-loop, webforms

I have  data base when there are user id there;
and I have a for loop, I want that the loop will run until the last ID
example: `for (i=0; i > something; i++)`
my question is what should be this something?
I also have the start of the code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string strLname;
    public string strEmail;
    public string strFname;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string dbPath = Server.MapPath(@"App_Data") + "/my_site.mdb";
        string connectionString = @"Data Source='" + dbPath + "';Provider='Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0';";
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        con.Open();
        string QueryString = "SELECT * FROM tbl_users";
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(QueryString, con);
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "tbl");
        con.Close();
        for (i=0; i < *something*; i++)

        }
    }
```

Comment: Small side comment, you may want to do `i < something`, else the loop might take a while for it to end... ;)

Comment: Yes it was a mistake, but do you nknow ehat should be this something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `rows count of table` at index 0 or what ever index you have.

```
for (i=0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{

}
```

Answer (score 3):

A `foreach` loop would be more convenient, wouldn't it?

```
foreach(DataRow row in ds.Tables["tbl"].Rows) {
    // ...
}
```

The ID would be `row["ID"]` in each row. (Or whatever you called it.)

And just in case you were planning on using `i` in a `for` loop as the ID, be careful if you ever delete rows.

Comment: For DataTables, it's convenient to do `foreach(DataRow row ds.Tables["tbl"].Rows)`, as you will get instances of `Object` otherwise, which is quite inconvenient...

Comment: @RenéWolferink: Ah, really? Thanks! (Why is that?)

Comment: `foreach` loops will autmatically cast the objects into the specified type if you don't use `var`. More info here: http://www.panopticoncentral.net/2004/06/09/for-each-and-option-strict/

Comment: If you look at the underlying IL code, you will find it will add a cast after getting the next value if the requested type is not the same as the provided type at compile time: `castclass [System.Data]System.Data.DataRow`

Comment: @RenéWolferink: I mean, why isn't it a collection of `DataRow`s in the first place? It is *called* a `DataRowCollection` after all.

Comment: Hi, thnk you for your answer, but the exercise is to do it in for loop, can you help me with this thing pleas?

Comment: Basically, backwards compatibility. It has implemented `ICollection` and `IEnumerable` (the non-generic ones) from the start. I guess they never bothered to add the generic enumerators on top.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you use foreach is much more better. 
something like,,,

```
foreach(DataRow dRow in ds.Table["Your Table Name"].Rows)
{
    //    dRow["id"] is your id column and you can access the value in that 
    //some sort of your operation code comparison or anything you want
}
```

Also i have noticed something in your code that you haven't used fail-safe.
so remember when you write code please don't forget to use try catch as you are dealing with database connection and related work.